# Deserializing XML response from Sharepoint 2007 Web services into Objects

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, sharepoint

So currently I managed to get an XML response with all the list items as:

```
XmlNode nodeListItems = ListObject.GetListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);
```

and when I check the output, it works fine (though- I think I eventually will want to have some kind of filter to avoid returning all results eventually).

The data looks like this when read as XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rs:data xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" ItemCount="3">
   <z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_h_id="123" ows_Status="Needs To Be Run" ows_Report_x0020_Type="Incremental Code Review" />

   <z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_h_id="456" ows_Status="On Master" ows_Report_x0020_Type="Code Review" />

   <z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_h_id="789" ows_Status="--" ows_Report_x0020_Type="Code Review" />
</rs:data>
```

How can I deserialize this to a class model such as:

```
public Class ItemList
   {
   public int Hid {get; set; }
   public string Status {get; set; }
   public string Type {get; set; }
   }
```

Is there any tool for managing the mapping between web services items to model objects?

I eventually will need to post data too, so that will be interesting...

Comment: Depend on what kind of web-services you use. For example WCF provide .wsdl file and Visual Studio can generate all classes provided in the wsdl file

Comment: I'm using the generic Web Services Access for Sharepoint 2007: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862916(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xml serialization attributes

```
[XmlRoot("data", Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("row", Namespace = "#RowsetSchema")]
    public List<ItemList> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class ItemList
{
    [XmlAttribute("ows_h_id")]
    public int Hid {get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ows_Status")]
    public string Status {get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ows_Report_x0020_Type")]
    public string Type {get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize it with XmlSerializer

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));

var data = (Data)serializer.Deserialize(yourStreamReader);
```

I have some doubts about attribute with name `ows_Report_x0020_Type`. Affraid the part `0020` can cause a problems during deserialization:

> Avoid having numeric characters in the attribute name

Comment: As for the naming scheme: its standard for XML response content in Web Services for SP2007